# Selenium Promise <rejected> Failed to Fetch at eval (eval at executeScript (:445:16))

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, twitter

I'm trying to make an automatic bot for posting tweets on Twitter. My idea is to use selenium to repeatedly send fetch requests. I have attempted replaying the fetch request on the console and it works. However, when I sent out a fetch request via selenium, it kept getting rejected. Sending it directly to the selenium console also gets rejected. What could be the problem?

Error:

`Promise{<rejected>: TypeError: Failed to Fetch at eval (eval at executeScript (:445:16), <anonymous>:3:37)..}`

Source Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import datetime
import json
from selenium.webdriver import Keys, ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
#chrome_options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=https://replit.com/@KhaelaFortunela/autovoter#Profile%202')
chrome_options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://twitter.com/home")

payload = '{"variables":{"tweet_text":"BRI sebagai BUMN mewujudkan komitmen untuk menciptakan lapangan pekerjaan yg bersifat berkelanjutan seperti Agen BRILink, serta penyaluran kredit KUR sebagai modal usaha yang diharapkan dapat memajukan ekonomi rakyat \n#TransformasiBRI127 #ROSBYWANI","media":{"media_entities":[],"possibly_sensitive":false},"withDownvotePerspective":false,"withReactionsMetadata":false,"withReactionsPerspective":false,"withSuperFollowsTweetFields":true,"withSuperFollowsUserFields":true,"semantic_annotation_ids":[],"dark_request":false},"features":{"view_counts_public_visibility_enabled":false,"tweetypie_unmention_optimization_enabled":true,"responsive_web_uc_gql_enabled":true,"vibe_api_enabled":true,"responsive_web_edit_tweet_api_enabled":true,"graphql_is_translatable_rweb_tweet_is_translatable_enabled":true,"interactive_text_enabled":true,"responsive_web_text_conversations_enabled":false,"responsive_web_twitter_blue_verified_badge_is_enabled":true,"verified_phone_label_enabled":false,"standardized_nudges_misinfo":true,"tweet_with_visibility_results_prefer_gql_limited_actions_policy_enabled":false,"responsive_web_graphql_timeline_navigation_enabled":true,"responsive_web_enhance_cards_enabled":true},"queryId":"sqNNr7rKZwnDQZkIiyvcrA"}'

fetch_req = '{"headers": {"accept": "*/*","accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9","authorization": "Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANRILgAAAAAAnNwIzUejRCOuH5E6I8xnZz4puTs%3D1Zv7ttfk8LF81IUq16cHjhLTvJu4FA33AGWWjCpTnA","content-type": "application/json","sec-fetch-dest": "empty","sec-fetch-mode": "cors","sec-fetch-site": "same-origin","x-csrf-token": "dc535379510138f59a330ed89961a6ef05f26b1d98eaf397c4b6999cdbbea319303dd54ec820339920d848cf5f000da1f15fa3434bf910d8e8d2d61aa2f9638f7c2beb52d000108c01e6dc772b0cf98c","x-twitter-active-user": "yes","x-twitter-auth-type": "OAuth2Session","x-twitter-client-language": "en"},"referrer": "https://mobile.twitter.com/compose/tweet","referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin","body": "payload","method": "POST", "mode": "cors","credentials": "include"}'


#while True:
for i in range(10):
  t = datetime.datetime.now()
  time_now = t.strftime("%X")
  y = json.loads(payload, strict=False)
  y['variables']['tweet_text'] = time_now + " " + y['variables']['tweet_text']
  new_payload = json.dumps(y)
  
  
  z = json.loads(fetch_req, strict=False)
  z['body'] = new_payload
  new_fetch_req = json.dumps(z)
  

  text = 'console.log(' + 'fetch("https://mobile.twitter.com/i/api/graphql/sqNNr7rKZwnDQZkIiyvcrA/CreateTweet"' + ',' + new_fetch_req + '))'
  driver.execute_script(text)
```

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: it's on the title, I'll add it to question body

Comment: did you update your Selenium driver to the latest version?

Comment: this is missing the code that does fetch. I would guess cors though since the domains do not match

Comment: yep it's selenium ver 4.7.0

Comment: there does an option to 'copy all as fetch', is that the reason this doesn't work?

Comment: the network tab (F12) will tell you why it failed

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing it wrong but I couldn't find it.. or maybe I just don't know how to look for it